# How to keep tables' placement static when toggling between tables

Tags: javascript, html, css

First post, so apologies for any no-nos...

I have two tables--one that records wood that I have in stock, and another that lists projects that will use that wood.

I set up a toggle for changing which one of the tables are displayed, but this causes the tables' positions to move around in their vertical position. One table is larger than the other, so I understand why it changes... but I'm not sure what the best way would be to control this change. I'd like to stop this motion if at all possible.

NOTE: I am new to HTML/CSS/JavaScript so there is probably a lot of mess in there. I tried to organize it, comments, etc.

JSFiddle:[https://jshttps://jsfiddle.net/L6sdgcrq/

```
/*
Start table styling block
*/
.tableStats {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 500px;
}

.tableContainer {
    width: 95%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#woodTable {
    width: 1200px;
    max-height: 400px;
    display: table;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-collapse: unset;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    padding: 10px !important;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border-bottom: none;
}

#projectTable {
    width: 1200px;
    max-height: 400px;
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-collapse: unset;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    padding: 10px !important;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border-bottom: none;
}

th {
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

td {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}

tr {
    padding: 10px;
}

tr:last-child, td:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}

td:nth-child(n+1) {
    border-left: 2px solid black;
}

th:first-child, td:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

.smaller {
    width: 50px;
}

/*
End table styling block
*/
```

You'll see what I'm talking about if you scroll to the top of the window in the executed portion.

Comment: Remove `height: 500px;` from `.tableStats`. Since you have a fixed height, the smaller table is aligning to the bottom. You don't want a fixed height on the container anyway since obviously the content of the tables will vary and it may overflow.

Comment: Do you know what effect you want to achieve? These tables have different columns count.

Comment: @EternalHour I did this but the table butts against the bottom of the screen, and makes the user have to scroll down farther to see the rest of the table. I wanted to find a way to have blank space at the bottom of the smaller table so that when the tables toggle, there's no window jerking around.

Comment: @RoboRobok The tables will have different columns almost assuredly. I'm OK with width of the tables but am getting all turned around trying to make their position fixed in the area where they are toggled...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding because what you are asking is not exactly clear. But if you want space then add a bottom margin to `.tableStats`.